# Mounting Microsoft Basic Data drives

Tags: mount, drive, disk-management, microsoft

I have recently dual booted and wanted to mount my windows drive on Linux. But when I try to do it, it says "Unable to mount". While windows system shows the partition as NTFS, Linux shows them as Windows basic data type. How can I mount it?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; this isn't a Linux support site, but a Ubuntu Q&A support site. You can `mount` in many ways depending on your chosen OS/release & thus defaults; we currently don't know what you've using, nor what you tried. You can use commands, store values in your system's *file-system table* so they're automatically used (*or available on request, ie. not auto-mounted*) etc.  What OS & release are you using?